# Set one element of each float4 in an array using CUDA/thrust

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, thrust

I have a fairly standard float4 class and an array of said float4s on the GPU. Each float4 represents an (x,y,z,rgba) point, and I'd like to use thrust to set the rgba value for each float4 in my array to a specific value. Seems like thrust::fill() might work with a custom iterator, but I don't know how to write a thrust iterator. Any ideas for how to do this?

```
(x1, y1, z1, c1), (x2, y2, z2, c2), .... --> (x1, y1, z1, value), (x2, y2, z2, value), ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seems like `thrust::fill()` might work with a custom iterator

It won't. `fill` is simple assignment. The destination iterator is not read, so it can't be modified. You don't want to do assignment over an iterator range, you want to modify an existing iterator range. `transform` will be the correct algorithm.

Write a functor, something like:

```
struct set_c
{
  float y;

  __host__ __device__
  set_c(const float val) : y(val) {};

  __host__ __device__
  myfloat4 operator()(const myfloat4& x)
  {
      myfloat4 val = x;
      val.c = y;
      return val;
  }
};
```

Then apply that functor over your data with transform in-place:

```
thrust::device_vector<myfloat4> data(bigconstant);
// something ...
set_c op(5.f); // set each myfloat4.c = 5.f
thrust::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), op);
```

All the code above obviously written in the browser and has never been near a compiler. Use at own risk.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this should work fine, this functor approach will be well suited for this particular need. Although, I also need to do things like finding the min element in my list in each axis, for that, would I be best to use a transform iterator?

Comment: For operations like minima you need to use a reduction. See https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions_ga5e9cef4919927834bec50fc4829f6e6b.html#ga5e9cef4919927834bec50fc4829f6e6b